# Git difftool not working Windows 10 Git Bash

Tags: python, git, difftool, diffmerge

I installed diffmerge and pasted this into my `.gitconfig` file in my `C:/Users` folder.

```
[diff]
    tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = C:/Program\\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe\"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"

[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = C:/Program\\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe-merge -result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

But now when I use `difftool` in git bash I get this

```
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 128: C:/Program Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exeC:\Users\Anas\AppData\Local\Temp/hhqGyv_calc.py: No such file or directory
fatal: external diff died, stopping at calc.py
```

Comment: Seems you missed a space in `sgdm.exe\"$LOCAL\"`, between `exe` and `\"$LOCAL`.

Comment: is there supposed to be a space? Let me try

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank You very much. It worked. Would you please tell me what I should do with this question? Should I keep it or close/delete it?

Comment: You also have: `sgdm.exe-merge` which should be `sgdm.exe -merge`.

Comment: @quamrana I didn't use the merge tool yet so. But still Thanks :)

Comment: @An4s911 You could write an answer and accept it so that others could find the solution if they are troubled by the similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I got this problem was I didn't leave a space after `sdgm.exe` in two different places.

First one is in line number 4 where I wrote `sdgm.exe\"LOCAL\"` instead it was supposed to be

`sdgm.exe \"LOCAL\"`.

And the second one is in line number 10 where I wrote `sdgm.exe-merge` instead it was supposed to be

`sdgm.exe -merge`

Thank You [@ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay) and  [@quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana) for helping me.